# Why is the Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic distribution free?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

## Context

Let $X_1,..X_n$ iid from X with an unknown cumulative distribution function F. Let $F_0$ be the hypothetized cdf of X. One may use the Kolmogorov-Smirnov (KS) statistic to test for the hypothesis test :
\begin{align}
H_0 : F = F_0 \\
H_1 : F \neq F_0 
\end{align}
The Kolmogorov-Smirnov (KS) statistic is :
\begin{align}
    D_n = sup_x |F_n(x)-F_0(x)|
\end{align}
The empirical cdf F_n(x) is :
\begin{align}
    F_n(x) = \frac{i}{n} \ \text{for} \ X_{(i)}\leq x < X_{(i+1)} i = 0,1..,n
\end{align}

## Question

I fail to understand the distribution-free property of the KS statistic.

If by $D^+_n$ I denote :
\begin{align}
    D^+_n = sup_x(F_n(x)-F_0(x))
\end{align}
Then I get the following :
\begin{align}
    D^+_n = \sup_x(F_n(x)-F_0(x)) &= \max_{0<i\leq n} \sup_{X_{(i)}\leq x < X_{(i+1)}} (F_n(x) - F_0(x)) \\
    &= \max_{0<i\leq n} \sup_{X_{(i)}\leq x < X_{(i+1)}} (F_0(x) - \frac{i}{n}) \\
    &= \max_{1<j\leq n+1} (F_0(X_{(j)}) - \frac{j-1}{n})
\end{align}
Which according to one of my textbook shows the distribution-free property of the KS statistic, because $(F_0(X_{(j)})$ would be the order statistic from a uniform distribution (0,1). I fail to understand why $(F_0(X_{(j)})$ are the order statistics from the uniform distribution.

Comment: If $(X_i)_{1\le i\le n}$ are i.i.d with a continuous distribution function $F$, then $(Y_i)_{1\le i\le n}$ with $Y_i=F(X_i)$ are i.i.d uniform on $(0,1)$. And $Y_{(j)}=F(X_{(j)})$.

Comment: Note also that the fact that $Y_{(j)}=F_0(X_{(j)})$ follows from the fact that $F_0$ is monotonous, so that the order is respected. In other words if $x_1<x_2<...<x_n$, than $F_0(x_1)<F_0(x_2)<...<F_0(x_n)$. ( this is hopefully just a clarification of @StubbornAtom comment )

Comment: Thank you I got it !